# Having a difficult time with segmented dropdown buttons

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I was taking a lesson on Udemy about inputs and dropdown buttons for bootstrap. The lesson was well until I decided to try and make a simple selection of albums for one of my favorite artists. The buttons separate from each other the moment I try getting them to the center underneath the photo of the artist. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?

I tried several things to have the buttons together. I tried mx-auto, justify-content-center, margins, and nothing really worked for me. Here is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
          <div class="mx-auto d-block">
            <img class="mx-auto d-block" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/7tCfeCWH4arhsTM-4Rz4IxWieQbegzibeXlG-kbytAujdk5dr2K0gBb8NG0Cvk6lB1dPkjyd=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj" width="250px" height="250px" alt="">
            <div class="input-group">
              <button class="btn btn-dark m-3">Bad Bunny Albums</button>
                <button 
                class="mx-auto d-block btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split m-3" 
                type="button" 
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Dropdown</span>
                </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">X 100pre</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Oasis</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">YHLQMDLG</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Las que no iban a salir</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">El Ultimo Tour Del Mundo</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Un Verano Sin Ti</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Rayhenandez what is problem? I didn't get it?

Answer (score 2):

Just add **me-0** in button "Bad Bunny Albums" and **ms-0** in dropdown button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script crossorigin="anonymous"
          integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container mt-3">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <form>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
          <div class="mx-auto d-block">
            <img alt=""
                 class="mx-auto d-block"
                 height="250px" src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/7tCfeCWH4arhsTM-4Rz4IxWieQbegzibeXlG-kbytAujdk5dr2K0gBb8NG0Cvk6lB1dPkjyd=s900-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj" width="250px">
            <div class="input-group">
              <button class="btn btn-dark m-3 me-0">Bad Bunny Albums</button>
              <button
                class="mx-auto d-block btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split m-3 ms-0"
                data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                type="button">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">X 100pre</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Oasis</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">YHLQMDLG</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Las que no iban a salir</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">El Ultimo Tour Del Mundo</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Un Verano Sin Ti</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsPy8.png HTML with below code:

```
<div class="input-group justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-dark m-0">Bad Bunny Albums</button>
    <button class="d-block btn btn-dark dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split m-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">X 100pre</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Oasis</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">YHLQMDLG</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Las que no iban a salir</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">El Ultimo Tour Del Mundo</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Un Verano Sin Ti</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please check working code, click the link:
[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kairavthakar2016/04wb67em/1/)

Please let me know if you find any issues.